# Javascript write underneath another element (on a new line)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create a function in JavaScript, that will write some text (which was retrieved with XMLHttpRequest) to a new element underneath the previous one.
To give you an example, imagine a chat room. When someone writes something new, a new line is created.

Also if possible how this would be in jQuery? 
I want to see if in jQuery would be much easier.

If you need anymore information please let me know!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: anything you got so far? html? js? tried **[Google](http://www.google.at/search?client=opera&rls=de&q=create+chat+in+jquery&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest)**?

Comment: Yes tried google but didn't find something. What do you mean what do I have so far? Obviously nothing because I have no idea what the previous should be in order to create the next one. Only the ajax request but that's irrelevant

Comment: have you ever used p tag? or ol/ul with some css? or even just br?

Comment: Ok now I know what you mean. The ajax request has an interval that refreshes every 4000 ms so if anything new appears to write it to the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In jquery you would have to do something like:

```
$('input').keyup(function(e){
      if (e.which == 13){
          //user has pressed enter, do a request
          var msg = $(this).val();
          //call a function and send what the user has entered 
          $.getJSON('chat.php', { msg:msg}, function(data){
                  if (data.success === true){ 
                  //if the call returned a success, add what has benn typed to the next element and clean the input
                  var newDiv = $('<div>');
                  newDiv .html(msg);
                  $(this).next().append(newDiv);
                  $(this).val('')
                  }
            });
     }

});
```

It's just a basic idea, you'd have to work on this

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much Nicola.

Comment: @Simos Mikelatos, if this is exactly what you wanted, **[accept this post as the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)**.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a good place to start?

```
$("#id").text($("#id").text() + "<br />" + newText);
```